# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 8080 keycloak with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, keycloak

port 8080 is overlapped by port 8180

This is the first time I'm launching an application with keycloack, spring boot and docker.
Setting up and working with keycloack itself did not cause any problems.
Docker runs smoothly.
But when I request from postman to spring methods, I get an error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak-auth
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.1

    command:
      - "start-dev"
    ports:
      - "8180:8080"
    networks:
      - keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: keycloak-db
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db
  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: keycloak-db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_keycloak:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks: [ keycloak ]
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10

  activemq:
    image: webcenter/activemq:latest
    ports:
      # mqtt
      - "1883:1883"
      # amqp
      - "5672:5672"
      # ui
      - "8161:8161"
      # stomp
      - "61613:61613"
      # ws
      - "61614:61614"
      # jms
      - "61616:61616"
    networks: [ activemq ]
    volumes: [ "activemq-data:/opt/activemq/conf", "activemq-data:/data/activemq", "activemq-data:/var/log/activemq" ]
    environment:
      ACTIVEMQ_REMOVE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT: "true"
      ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_LOGIN: admin
      ACTIVEMQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
      ACTIVEMQ_WRITE_LOGIN: write
      ACTIVEMQ_WRITE_PASSWORD: password
      ACTIVEMQ_READ_LOGIN: read
      ACTIVEMQ_READ_PASSWORD: password
      ACTIVEMQ_JMX_LOGIN: jmx
      ACTIVEMQ_JMX_PASSWORD: password

      ACTIVEMQ_STATIC_TOPICS: static-topic-1;static-topic-2;autoTopic
      ACTIVEMQ_STATIC_QUEUES: static-queue-1;static-queue-2
      ACTIVEMQ_ENABLED_SCHEDULER: "true"
      ACTIVEMQ_MIN_MEMORY: 512
      ACTIVEMQ_MAX_MEMORY: 2048

networks:
  keycloak:
    name: keycloak
    driver: bridge
  activemq: { }

volumes:
  postgres_data_keycloak:
    driver: local
  activemq-data:
    driver: local
```

securityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                //TODO: security without @PreAuthorize
                /* .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").hasRole("PERSON")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )*/
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Configurer -> oauth2Configurer
                        .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer
                                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> {
                                    Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");
                                    Collection<String> roles = realmAccess.get("roles");

                                    var grantedAuthorities = roles.stream()
                                            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                                    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
                                })));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AutomobileRestController implements AutomobileResource, AutomobileOpenApi, JMSPublisher {

    private final AutomobileRepository repository;
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public static double getTiming(Instant start, Instant end) {
        return Duration.between(start, end).toMillis();
    }

    @Transactional
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        repository.save(new Automobile(1L, "Ford", "Green", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now(), true, false));
    }

    @PostMapping("/automobiles")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    //@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public Automobile saveAutomobile(@Valid @RequestBody Automobile automobile) {
        log.info("saveAutomobile() - start: automobile = {}", automobile);
        Automobile savedAutomobile = repository.save(automobile);
        log.info("saveAutomobile() - end: savedAutomobile = {}", savedAutomobile.getId());
        return savedAutomobile;
    }

    @GetMapping("/automobiles")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public Collection<Automobile> getAllAutomobiles() {
        log.info("getAllAutomobiles() - start");
        Collection<Automobile> collection = repository.findAll();
        log.info("getAllAutomobiles() - end");
        return collection;
    }

    @GetMapping("/automobiles/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('PERSON')")
    public Automobile getAutomobileById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.info("getAutomobileById() - start: id = {}", id);
        Automobile receivedAutomobile = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(ThereIsNoSuchAutoException::new);
        if (receivedAutomobile.getDeleted()) {
            throw new AutoWasDeletedException();
        }
        log.info("getAutomobileById() - end: Automobile = {}", receivedAutomobile.getId());
        return receivedAutomobile;
    }

    @Hidden
    @GetMapping(value = "/automobiles", params = {"name"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Collection<Automobile> findAutomobileByName(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
        log.info("findAutomobileByName() - start: name = {}", name);
        Collection<Automobile> collection = repository.findByName(name);
        log.info("findAutomobileByName() - end: collection = {}", collection);
        return collection;
    }

    @PutMapping("/automobiles/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    //@CachePut(value = "automobile", key = "#id")
    public Automobile refreshAutomobile(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Automobile automobile) {
        log.info("refreshAutomobile() - start: id = {}, automobile = {}", id, automobile);
        Automobile updatedAutomobile = repository.findById(id)
                .map(entity -> {
                    entity.checkColor(automobile);
                    entity.setName(automobile.getName());
                    entity.setColor(automobile.getColor());
                    entity.setUpdateDate(automobile.getUpdateDate());
                    if (entity.getDeleted()) {
                        throw new AutoWasDeletedException();
                    }
                    return repository.save(entity);
                })
                //.orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Automobile not found with id = " + id));
                .orElseThrow(ThereIsNoSuchAutoException::new);
        log.info("refreshAutomobile() - end: updatedAutomobile = {}", updatedAutomobile);
        return updatedAutomobile;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/automobiles/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @CacheEvict(value = "automobile", key = "#id")
    public String removeAutomobileById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.info("removeAutomobileById() - start: id = {}", id);
        Automobile deletedAutomobile = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(ThereIsNoSuchAutoException::new);
        deletedAutomobile.setDeleted(Boolean.TRUE);
        repository.save(deletedAutomobile);
        log.info("removeAutomobileById() - end: id = {}", id);
        return "Deleted";
    }

    @Hidden
    @DeleteMapping("/automobiles")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void removeAllAutomobiles() {
        log.info("removeAllAutomobiles() - start");
        repository.deleteAll();
        log.info("removeAllAutomobiles() - end");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/automobiles", params = {"color"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Collection<Automobile> findAutomobileByColor(
            @Parameter(description = "Name of the Automobile to be obtained. Cannot be empty.", required = true)
            @RequestParam(value = "color") String color) {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        log.info("findAutomobileByColor() - start: time = {}", start);
        log.info("findAutomobileByColor() - start: color = {}", color);
        Collection<Automobile> collection = repository.findByColor(color);
        Instant end = Instant.now();
        log.info("findAutomobileByColor() - end: milliseconds = {}", getTiming(start, end));
        log.info("findAutomobileByColor() - end: collection = {}", collection);
        return collection;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/automobiles", params = {"name", "color"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Collection<Automobile> findAutomobileByNameAndColor(
            @Parameter(description = "Name of the Automobile to be obtained. Cannot be empty.", required = true)
            @RequestParam(value = "name") String name, @RequestParam(value = "color") String color) {
        log.info("findAutomobileByNameAndColor() - start: name = {}, color = {}", name, color);
        Collection<Automobile> collection = repository.findByNameAndColor(name, color);
        log.info("findAutomobileByNameAndColor() - end: collection = {}", collection);
        return collection;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/automobiles", params = {"colorStartsWith"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Collection<Automobile> findAutomobileByColorStartsWith(
            @RequestParam(value = "colorStartsWith") String colorStartsWith,
            @RequestParam(value = "page") int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size") int size) {
        log.info("findAutomobileByColorStartsWith() - start: color = {}", colorStartsWith);
        Collection<Automobile> collection = repository
                .findByColorStartsWith(colorStartsWith, PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("color")));
        log.info("findAutomobileByColorStartsWith() - end: collection = {}", collection);
        return collection;
    }

    @GetMapping("/automobiles-names")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<String> getAllAutomobilesByName() {
        log.info("getAllAutomobilesByName() - start");
        List<Automobile> collection = repository.findAll();
        List<String> collectionName = collection.stream()
                .map(Automobile::getName)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.info("getAllAutomobilesByName() - end");
        return collectionName;
    }

    @Override
    @PostMapping("/message")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Automobile> pushMessage(@RequestBody Automobile automobile) {
        try {
            Topic autoTopic = Objects.requireNonNull(jmsTemplate
                    .getConnectionFactory()).createConnection().createSession().createTopic("AutoTopic");
            Automobile savedAutomobile = repository.save(automobile);
            log.info("\u001B[32m" + "Sending Automobile with id: " + savedAutomobile.getId() + "\u001B[0m");
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(autoTopic, savedAutomobile);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(savedAutomobile, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: App
  profiles:
    active: development
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/automobiles
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update 
    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/automobile-realm
  jms:
    pub-sub-domain: true
  activemq:
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
server:
  port: 8080  
  servlet:
    context-path: /demo
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework: info
    org.springframework.security: debug
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: debug
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html 
  api-docs:
    path: /v3/api-docs.yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

When I make a request I get an error:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

In keycloak itself the following port settings
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I checked that the port is not busy during the request, and keycloak works on port 8180. Maybe I missed some setting?

DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD /target/spring-boot-keycloak-docker-postgres.jar spring-boot-keycloak-docker-postgres.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-boot-keycloak-docker-postgres.jar"]
```

docker-compose

[image]

logger docker-compose
[image]

Comment: I've already tried everything: 1) changed ports 2) allow port 8080 through the firewall 3) install docker 4) connected to keyсloak 5) without keyсlock the application works

Comment: have you tried 8180 instead of 8080 in postman?

Comment: @Aakash yes, I tried, but it works for me on 8180 keyсlock, and on 8080 spring boot. I get the error: "error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8180/demo/api/automobiles/3"

Comment: From your docker compose, I don't find reference to your Spring Boot app. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Aakash you mean DockerFile ? I updated the question description and add DockerFile
Maybe i don't understand question?

Comment: How are you referring to your Dockerfile or application image from your docker-compose.yml? I see the only services started from your docker-compose are keycloak, keycload-db and activemq. If you start your app using docker-compose, how it is starting your spring boot project? Do you see some logs from your app?

Comment: @Aakash Logs from my application are not visible in docker. It turns out that i need to add the spring service in the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Your docker compose does not refer to your spring service and hence, it's not even started. Even though keycloak is started, your service isn't. That's why you are not able to access your service's endpoints.

Comment: @Aakash Can you tell me what the docker-compose.yml file with the application service should look like? 
I looked similar on the Internet, then it blocks Docker for me.

Comment: You can create an image of your spring service using docker (ref: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/) , and use it as any other service in your docker compose.

Comment: happy to help. I am posting the solution as an answer here. Please upvote and select as correct answer to help me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your spring boot app is not getting started via your docker-compose file. This file is only starting up keycloak, it's DB and active mq services.

You should package your spring boot app as a docker image (https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/) and use that as another service in your docker compose file.